# How to trigger automatic plugin updates in Wordpress 5.5

Tags: automatic-updates

I would like to be able to test automatic updates of plugins that I have developed. After enabling auto updates for individual plugins on the plugins page, how can I trigger the update or when can I expect the updates to take place?

Comment: You can use https://wordpress.org/plugins/stops-core-theme-and-plugin-updates/, to force update.

Comment: I have looked at the plugin but it is not clear if it can trigger updates only for those plugin that have been set to auto update.

Answer (score 2):

Call `wp_maybe_auto_update();` function after the `init` hook. Or follow this method http://blog.birdhouse.org/2013/11/02/force-wordpress-auto-update/